# How can I pass data doInBackground inside a snippet in other class?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

I have a class to do an AsyncTask that is working fine and I can pass the data to my mainActivity. Now I have the problem that I don't know how to can handle this data in other places in my MainActivity. I want to use this data in a snippet (marker) to put some information in the marker:

AsyncTask class.

```
public class DistanceBetweenLocations extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    URL url;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        StringBuilder result = null;
        String duration = "";
        String distance = "";

        try {
             url = new URL(params[0]);
        }catch (MalformedURLException m){

        }

        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        }catch (IOException e){

        }

        try {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
        }catch (IOException e){

        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.toString());
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rows");
            JSONObject object_rows = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray jsonArrayElements = object_rows.getJSONArray("elements");
            JSONObject  object_elements = jsonArrayElements.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject object_duration = object_elements.getJSONObject("duration");
            JSONObject object_distance = object_elements.getJSONObject("distance");

            duration = object_duration.getString("text");
            distance = object_distance.getString("text");

            return distance + ", " + duration + " Driving";

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        MainActivity mp = new MainActivity();
        mp.getDataFromAsyncTask(s);
    }
}
```

This is the method that I get the data in my MainActivity that is a Fragment:

```
 public void getDataFromAsyncTask(String result) {
        getDistanceAndTime = result + km;
    }
```

And I want to use this data here:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(geoPoint.getLatitude(), geoPoint.getLongitude()))
                                .title(name.getName())
                                .snippet(getDistanceAndTime)//here is where I want to put the data that I get in getDataFromAsyncTask
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
```

This is that I'm trying, but I get a no data:

I have a global variable that I'm using in my getDataFromAsyncTask and put in my snippet, but he take first the data of the inicialization:

```
String getDistanceAndTime

public void getDataFromAsyncTask(String result) {
            getDistanceAndTime = result + km;
        }

  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(geoPoint.getLatitude(), geoPoint.getLongitude()))
                                    .title(name.getName())
                                    .snippet(getDistanceAndTime)//here is where I want to put the data that I get in getDataFromAsyncTask
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do when handling such scenarios - communication between classes; make your code as decoupled as possible. With that in mind, Events come to play!

- Create an Event class (Plain Old Java Object POJO) with a variable (boolean isCompleted and a value you need to update your marker - obtained from AsyncTask). Your constructor should take values to set these variables inside onPostExecute. This is where you notify your activity of the event. `EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventClassName(true, value));`
- Using of the event libraries - my favorite is EventBus, inside your `onPostExecute()` method of the AsyncTask, you can pass back the new value to the activity.
- The activity must register (subscribe) to the event you created in step 1 by doing `EventBus.getDefault().register(this)`
- You also must unregister inside onDestroy of your activity or Fragment.
- Now, finally, you need to add a method with the following signature to your activity - this method will catch the event posted from onPostExecute() and must look like this : `public void onEvent(EventClassName event)`
- Inside this method, you should call a method that updates your Marker or update it directly if you prefer!

To use EventBus library, simply add this to your build.gradle dependecies

```
 compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

You should be good to go! Good luck and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

In onPostExecute method you are instantiating the activity yourself, it just serves no purpose, activity is instantiated by the system. If you are calling the AsyncTask from MainActivity, then pass the reference to it and then call your method using that reference.

Answer (score 0):

There's a misunderstanding about your code here:

```
MainActivity mp = new MainActivity();
mp.getDataFromAsyncTask(s);
```

In Android, you don't create activity object instances.  Android creates them for you when you start the activity.

To pass a string or other data to an activity, you can put that data in the intent that starts the activity, then you pull that data out of the intent during the activity's onCreate() to work with it.  This is one of the most fundamental practices in Android, and [the documentation for that is here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).